# "by the window" vs. "near the window"

Tags: prepositions, difference, synonyms

What is the difference between *by* and *near*? According to Oxford *living* Dictionaries, the meanings seem to be identical

> **[by](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/by)**
>   **5.** Indicating location of a physical object beside a place or object:
>
> **[near](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/near)**
>   **1.** At or to a short distance away from (a place):

Which preposition should I choose between the two?

> I am sitting **by/near** the window.

Comment: They're both fine, and mean exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct. "By" indicates a greater degree of closeness than "near". You could replace "by" with "next to" without any loss of meaning.